# Can keys be remapped in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, netbeans

Is there a way to remap the keys on a Macbook running macOS 10.15.3, having the right alt key behaving as the left alt key? Apparently there is a difference, because I'm running into the issue where the [option (⌥ / alt) keys are not recognised after pressing right-hand option (⌥ / alt) key](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1850) in NetBeans 11.2.

As I'm disabled, it makes it really hard for me to use the left alt key in combination with the arrow keys, which makes it hard to extend selections with words in NetBeans (and that's something I use a lot). So I hope there is a solution for this other than waiting for the NetBeans developers to fix this.

Comment: This **might** be possible with something like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) - Left alt is 0x80120 & Right alt is 0x80140, so the two are in fact registered differently to the OS itself, even if nominally it treats them the same. I've never used Karabiner myself, so can't really help with the details.

Comment: I was just checking out that tool, and it's working as a charm. It needed a reboot and some permissions though.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you want to set up your own answer, go ahead, as you'll have better detail than my vague hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping keys is possible using [Karabiner-Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Make sure to reboot after installing. When starting the tool it will prompt you to set privacy permissions. Do so in the settings:

[image]

Now it just a matter of setting the mapping:

[image]

See also https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/getting-started/installation/